# How to get list of attribute names with XML::LibXML::Reader?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I try to process XML nodes which may have many data in attributes. I'd like to get list of attributes, but can't figure out, how to achieve it with [XML::LibXML::Reader](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Reader.pod)?

With `attributeCount` I can get count of attributes and the with `getAttributeNo` iterate over them, but this gives me just values, not attribute names.

I hoped to see something like `getAttributes`, but there is no such [method for attributes](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Reader.pod#METHODS-PROCESSING-ATTRIBUTES)

Sample code:

```perl
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;

use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(IO => \*DATA)
    or die "Cannot read from \\*DATA\n";

while ($reader->read) {
  processNode($reader);
}

sub processNode {
  my $reader = shift;


  if ( $reader->name eq 'item' ) {
    my $count = $reader->attributeCount; 
    say "item has $count attributes";

    for (my $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
      say $reader->getAttributeNo( $i );
    }

    # this would my desired way to access attributes:
    # for my $attr ( $reader->getAttributes ) { 
    #   say "$attr ". $reader->getAttribute( $attr );
    # }
  }
}

__DATA__
<items>
  <item code="PK7000346" name="Lucky" class="MUU" purchaseprice="0.2983" object="UPK" hasvariants="0" ts="2019-06-19T20:04:47"/>
</items>
```

Desired output is hash or pairs of name/value, like this:

```
code PK7000346
name Lucky
class MUU
purchaseprice 0.2983
object UPK
hasvariants 0
ts 2019-06-19T20:04:47
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a shallow copy of the node:

```
if ($reader->name eq 'item'
    && $reader->nodeType == XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT
) {
    for my $attr ($reader->copyCurrentNode(0)->getAttributes) {
        say join '=', $attr->name, $attr->value;
    }
}
```

It seems `getAttributes` is not documented in neither [XML::LibXML::Element](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::Element) nor [XML::LibXML::Node](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::Node). You can also use `attributes`, or treat the element as a hash reference and ask for its keys:

```
    my $item = $reader->copyCurrentNode(0);
    for my $attr (keys %$item) {
        say join '=', $attr, $item->{$attr};
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate, where from the `getAttributes` method comes? What object the copied node is?

Comment: XML::LibXML::Element.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach using [`moveToAttribute`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Reader):

```
sub processNode {
  my $reader = shift;

  if ( $reader->name eq 'item' ) {
      my $count = $reader->attributeCount;
      for (my $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
          $reader->moveToAttributeNo( $i );
          say $reader->name, " = ", $reader->value;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, I did not figure to use `$reader->name` together with `moveToAttribute`.